# Using turtlesim

Tags: gazebo, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm thinking about simulating a ROS robot running a maze. I thought of using TurtleSim instead of Gazebo because: it is lighter weight with only 2d, and I would be able to define the maze in two dimensions which would be easier.

I have a few basic questions about TurtleSim:

1. Is there a way to define "obstacles" or "walls" in TurtleSim?
2. I guess this amounts to the same: does it simulate a Lidar or similar sensor?

Or should I ignore all the other simulators and stick with Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268583/using-turtlesim/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Or should I ignore all the other simulators and stick with Gazebo?

Using turtlesim for this is probably not a good idea: it wasn't made for this and will require quite some work.

I suggest you take a look at [stdr_simulator](http://wiki.ros.org/stdr_simulator).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1